# Generating TIFF with Apache FOP 1.0 - TIFFImageEncoder4

Tags: java, tiff, apache-fop

I have successfully been using Apache FOP to generate a PDF using an Ant task.
I also have Java code (Web Service using Axis2) successfully working and producing PDFs, but have been using the Ant Task as it's much faster to properly test my stylesheet.

Now that I have PDF working, I tried to meet the second requirement of the project I am working on - that is generating a TIFF. Same stylesheet, same source document, but output is a TIFF.

The ANT task looks like the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="FOPAnt" default="generate-pdf-from-transform" basedir=".">
<property name="fop.home" value="D:\Dev\Java\libraries\fop-1.0-bin\fop-1.0"/>

<taskdef name="fop" classname="org.apache.fop.tools.anttasks.Fop">
  <classpath>
    <fileset dir="${fop.home}/lib">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${fop.home}/build">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\Dev\Java\FopConverter\workspace\FOPAnt\build.xml:30: java.lang.Error: TIFFImageEncoder4
```

I have googled and googled for this error, and it seems as though there is a requirement to include JAI ImageIO tools in the class path.

The recurring reference I found is this:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49681

I noticed the jai_imageio.jar is actually already in my `${fop.home}/build` folder.
I'm a bit of a Java newbie, so correct me if I'm wrong, but looks to me like the JAR is included in the classpath already in my above ANT script?

I have tried using the webservice - have added the jai_imageio.jar to the build path and it is going into `WEB-INF/lib` - getting the same error.
Have tried using different colour configurations as suggested in that Bug thread, but no luck.

Really struggling with this. It's frustrating, as the PDF generation worked well.
Hit a bit of a brick wall with this.

EDIT: After more research, I should maybe point out I'm using Windows 7 x64. I will re-install an x86 JRE (will try JRE 7).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it is ImageIO **TOOLS** and not just ImageIO; two completely different things.

Here are the libraries I use in my FOP-based TIFF generator; I avoid the XML config and go straight with my own custom renderer:

- avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar
- batik-all-1.7.jar
- commons-io-1.4.jar
- commons-logging.jar
- fop.jar
- jai_imageio.jar
- log4j-1.2.13.jar
- xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar
- xmlgraphics-commons-1.4.jar

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by following these steps:

1. Install JRE 1.4 on target server (Jai image io tools needs this
   to install). Has to be x86 (32bit).
       a)  j2re-1_4_2_19-windows-i586-p.exe works
2. Install JRE7 (again, has to be x86)
3. Install Tomcat6 - setting JRE7 as it's JRE.
4. Ensure JAVA_HOME is set as the root JRE7 folder.
5. Ensure %JAVA_HOME%\bin is in the PATH variable
6. Install jai_imageio-1_1-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe. It should install into JRE7.

I am on x64 and had x64 JRE and JDK installed. This this was the root of my problem.

This fixed it so my webservice works in TomCat. Haven't tried the ANT Task yet. JAI ImageIO Tools seems to have a dependency on DLLs, which work only in 32bit.
I assume this would not work fine in Eclipse if 32 bit, and pointing at 32bit JDK/JRE